# Matplotlib animation of multiple lines being defined in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 'n' lines whose x and y coordinates are defined by sk_x(t, tau) and sk_y(t, tau) respectively. If I plot them with the same function outside of the loop it plots the function fine but I can't make them work within the animate(i) function. An empty plot appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears. The problem definitely is how I'm handling the animate function but I can't quite figure out what's wrong, it worked with tau being the parameter instead of t but not the other way round (see second bit of code).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


v = 1
k = 1
b = 1
c = 100
f = 200

def sk_y(t, tau):
    y = v*(t-tau)
    return y

def sk_x(t, tau):
    x = v*(np.log((1+k*t)/(1+k*tau)))/k
    return x

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, sk_x(c,0)), ylim=(0, sk_y(c,0)))
lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(200)]

def init():
    m = 0
    while m < c:
        lines[m].set_data([], [])
        m+=1
    return lines


def animate(i):
    n=-1
    while n<c:
        n+=1
        t = np.linspace(0,i/2-n,100)
        x = sk_x(t+n, n)
        y = sk_y(t+n, n)
        lines[n].set_data(x, y)
    return lines   #edited in 


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=f, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Using this bit for the animate function works fine

```
def animate(i):
    tau = np.linspace(i*c/f, 0,100)
    x = sk_x(c, tau)
    y = sk_y(c, tau)
    lines[0].set_data(x, y)
    return lines
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Added the return function in the animate function, but it still doesn't work for all the lines simultaneously as I want it to.

Comment: the function `animate` doesn't return the Artist objects, try to add this return statement

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! This works for each individual line but it still doesn't seem to be working for all the lines simultaneously.

Comment: hmm i've just tried the code and i got a colorful rainbow, could you specify what's not working exactly ? Maybe is it only an indentation issue ? because the return statement in your post looks fine

Comment: It's working now, just pasted my code into a new file and works perfectly, no idea what was going on there. Thanks so much!